# Imported Google Fonts' font weight doesnt work in some computers

Tags: html, css, vue.js, fonts, google-font-api

So recently I posted a a question about how my fonts in my website cannot go lighter than font weight 600. Here is the question [Open Sans font weight cannot go lighter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72975484/open-sans-font-weight-cannot-go-lighter/72976222#72976222)

So I was able to solve it by just importing the google font along with the desired font-weight. I have now thinner fonts(font-weight:300).

The problem is, I found out that when I deployed to app to a live server, the font weights that I set doesn't work when I view the site in my own computer. On some computers it works fine, the thinner font weights are working but there are other computers too that have the same issue.

I'm not sure what is happening here. I'm thinking of the fonts installed in my local machine has something to do with this, but when I test the site in localhost the font-weights are correct and displays correctly.

Comment: are you 100% sure your browser hasn't cached the wrong version of fonts or css?

Comment: @StamatisValis, yes I'm sure. Even if I try it on different browsers it's still the same problem.

Comment: cause you said "Strange though, on other computers it works fine" maybe its a path issue.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know most browsers don’t fully support the numerical values for font-weight . also Google font isn't calibrated to carry all of the weights you want with it. Some font problems can be fixed by deleting and reinstalling the font you are using on your local machine.

Comment: So I need to install the font on my machine even though in the browser, in my CSS it is being imported already?

Comment: it may solve your local machine problem cause as you said it works fine on other machines. also you could check the font setting on the other machine and compare it to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the codepen at the end of this package Readme, it has an Open Sans example with many weights. What do you see?

It has a lot of examples and explanation there, maybe you see something you missed.

https://github.com/adriano-tirloni/google-fonts-css2